# How do I get energy distribution of radiation (Planck's Law) in terms of frequency?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, thermal-radiation

I have $$u(\lambda) d\lambda = \frac{8\pi hc\lambda^{-5}}{e^{hc/\lambda kT} - 1}d\lambda$$

I want this in terms of frequency. I can start with $\lambda =c/f$ but I will end up with $u(c/f)$ rather than $u(f)$. Also, what else what I do other than just a pure substitution?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Idk, but something's wrong with you for sure.

Comment: With due respect: it's not unreasonable to expect some measure of prior research before posting a question.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero It's also reasonable to expect, that with the time it takes to post a comment complaining about a question, you could maybe... answer it? But at the very least just leave your downvote and go

Comment: @ZeroTheHero There's no problem posting a redundant question if it helps future students finding the answer quicker.

Comment: I removed the comment you refer to as quickly as I could as it was not terribly fair.  Nothing more to say.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero "actually there is a problem" I'm sure in your mind, you are always right and have no need to explain yourself.

Comment: Maybe this link https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/how-to-stop-asking-duplicate-questions will be useful when it comes to duplicates or near-duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $u(\lambda)$ as you described, the function you want is the function $\rho(f)$ that satisfies
$$
  \rho(f)\,df = u(\lambda)\,d\lambda
\tag{1}
$$
so that both sides give the same result when integrated over a given range (using $\lambda =c/f$ to relate the two ranges, of course). As you noted, $\rho(f)$ is not simply $u(c/f)$, because we also have
$$
d\lambda=\frac{-c}{f^2}df.
\tag{2}
$$
When (2) is used in (1), the function $\rho(f)$ ends up with $f^3$ in the numerator instead of $f^5$.